# offline PWA view with bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I'm working in an offline view for PWA, I need to design this view (or very similar)

[image]

I have tried with this

```
@extends('layouts.app_site')
@push('styles')
@endpush
@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="ibox product-detail">
                <div class="ibox-content">
                    <div class="alert alert-dark" role="alert">
                        You are currently offline
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                            <img src="{{asset('img/gp_no_image.png')}}">
                            <h1>
                                You are currently offline
                            </h1>
                            We couldn't load the next page on this connection. Please try again.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-footer text-center">
                        <a href=""
                           class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Retry Connection</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
@push('scripts')
@endpush
```

And this is my result (ignore the background image)

[image]

How can I change the upper alert style like the example image? (use all ibox-content and black color)
and how can I make the retry button bigger?

- for alerts, I'm using [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/)
- for buttons, I'm using [inspinia
  styles](http://webapplayers.com/inspinia_admin-v2.9.3/buttons.html)

thanks

Comment: please add your css file